# Any potential fixes for an executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python g++ make]: exit code: 1 error?

Tags: python, docker

I am running through the Docker setup tutorial located at: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/

When running the docker file containing the code:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

I get the following error message:

```
=> ERROR [2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make
------                                              
#9 0.514 fetch https://dlcdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#9 3.656 fetch https://dlcdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#9 5.174 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#9 5.218   python (no such package):
#9 5.218     required by: world[python]
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache python g++ make]: exit code: 1
```

Any ideas on what this error could be? I tried searching around, but found nothing that seems like it would be helpful. Thank you all for your time and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different image that already has python, so

```
FROM python:3-alpine
```

You can also try to replace the apk add command with

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 g++ make
```

Comment: Thank you @Ellie! That worked! Also, thank you Paul for fixing the formatting on my original question.

The follow up error I get is:

`=> ERROR [stage-1 5/5] RUN yarn install --production`

`  > [stage-1 5/5] RUN yarn install --production:`

`#13 0.541 /bin/sh: yarn: not found`

`executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --production]: exit code: 127`

I tried searching here again, but couldn't find much. Any other brilliance from your end that could help me out? I'll keep looking to see what I can find.

Comment: Scratch that! Got it figured out. I had to pull the rest of the documents from the sample app at https://github.com/docker/getting-started/tree/master/app and run the docker build command from the same directory. Thank you again Ellie and and Paul H!

Comment: @TigerJohn3 I am getting the same error of `#14 0.136 /bin/sh: yarn: not found`-> `executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --production]: exit code: 127`. I am running the  `docker build ` command from the **app** directory. Should I run the command from some other directory or do something else? Cheers in advance for the help.